# The command works on terminal but doesn't work in java program

Tags: java, linux, terminal, runtime, exec

I wrote a process manager program one of the things that it does is to exit all running processes when it shut down 
,so there is the code

```
public void stop_all() throws IOException {
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 -1");
   System.out.println("killed");
}
```

and there is the action on the button

```
private void exitButton(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
Run ob = new Run();
    try {
        ob.stop_all();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(mainmenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

this.dispose();
```

}

i have no idea why it doesn't work ,
i execute that command in the terminal and it works fine

please help :)

Comment: You can try to read the process' output to see if there are any errors, [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149828/read-the-output-from-java-exec) but my guess is that this Java program doesn't have the necessary permissions to run that command.

Comment: What do you mean by "program"? Do you mean a .jar? If so try running the jar in terminal with java -jar and post the error output

Comment: Are you not getting any exception/error? If yes, please post it here.

Comment: i don't get any error or exception
by debugging i found that the code pass by the function and run it and it doesn't do what it should do

Answer (score 0):

I am still skeptical about the permissions of the program. But, from this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031954/java-runtime-exec-throws-no-such-file-or-permission-denied) you need to specify the command path in your exec().

So your code should probably be:

```
public void stop_all() throws IOException {
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/kill -9 -1");
   System.out.println("killed");
}
```

Comment: it is still doesn't work
and in addition to my question there is another function contains kill commands works fine